# StringReplace unable to identify and replace string copied into clipboard from web pages?

Tags: string, clipboard, autohotkey, str-replace

What I am trying to do is very simple: copying selected text into clipboard and replacing every occurrence of some words with others.

[**StringReplace**](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm) replaces the specified substring with a new string, so it would be what I am actually looking for.

This small script should copy the text highlighted by user into clipboard, look for every occurrence of the strings `<name>`, `<class>` and `<race>` and replace them with strings `Aerien`, `Paladin` and `Human`:

```
^q::
{
    Send, ^c
    ClipWait
    StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, <name>, Aerien, All
    StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, <class>, Paladin, All
    StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, <race>, human, All
    Sleep, 250
    Send, ^v
}
Return
```

At the end, it pastes the new content.

Well, said that... try to use it on the contents of [**this**](http://wotlk.openwow.com/quest=783) web page as instance, especially where it's written:

> I hope you strapped your belt on tight, young <**class**>, because
>   there is work to do here in Northshire.

Aforementioned script returns me always `<class>` instead of replacing that string with `Paladin`. Using the same script within Notepad instead of within that web page sometimes work but more often not.

I am guessing some issues with `<` and `>` symbols.

Comment: I thought `<class>` is supposed to be replaced with `Paladin`, not with `human`!? Anyway, try to only `StringReplace` an internal variable: Put the clipboard contents into a variable and apply `StringReplace` to that variable. Finally, insert the variable back into the clipboard.

Comment: It actually worked replacing `clipboard` with a new variable after each `StringReplace`.

Comment: You don't a new variable after each `StringReplace`. You only need to define it once (in the beginning), then `StringReplace` using **only** that variable. If you've found a solution, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Always use AutoHotkey from http://ahkscript.org/ (current version, new official website)! AutoHotkey from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems running scripts with it!*

Your script works as intended. When you press CTRL+q script copies to clipboard selected text (so you have to select text before pressing CTRL+q), then in a text that is in clipboard it searches for `<name>`, `<class>`, `<race>` and replaces them respectively to `Aerien`, `Paladin`, `Human`. After it pastes the content of clipboard to the current active window.
 
1. If you need to paste the content of clipboard in specific input field of current active window, then in my opinion the best way to do that is to use [ImageSearch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) command to get coordinates of that input field, after make click in theses coordinates and after paste the content of clipboard. But also keep in mind that there can be other solutions to do the some.
2. If you need to paste content of clipboard in some other window, activate that window with [WinActivate](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm) command and then paste the content of clipboard.